# Erro usando o PDO e Autoload

Tags: php, pdo

Estou tendo um problema para fazer uma chamada do PDO dentro de um arquivo que funciona com um autoload, acredito que o autoload tenta carregar tudo , até mesmo o PDO.

```
 <?php
 function load($namespace)
 {       
    $namespace=str_replace("\\","/",$namespace);
    $caminhoAbsoluto=__DIR__."/".$namespace.".php";
    return include $caminhoAbsoluto;
 }

spl_autoload_register(__NAMESPACE__."\load");
 ?>
```

Código do arquivo onde tento usar o PDO.

```
<?php
 namespace Model\login;
 class validar{
 public function teste(){
  $this->buscar();
  }

public function buscar(){
$query="SELECT*from usuario where senha=36398020";
    $con=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=login','root','36398020');
    $rest=$con->query($query);
    $rest->fetchAll();
    return $rest;
    }
  }

  ?>
```

O nevegador me retorna esse aviso:  **Warning: include(C:\wamp64\www\Agenda/Model/login/PDO.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp64\www\Agenda\autoload.php on line 5**

Comment: Acredito que o `$caminhoAbsoluto=__DIR__."/".$namespace.".php";` simplesmente não funciona por quê o PDO não está neste caminho, então seu autoloader deveria ser adaptado para carrega-lo diretamente da DLL ou então ignora-lo e deixar o PHP lidar com a requisição da classe sozinho. Acho que seria importante você informar em qual versão do PHP isto está acontecendo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não tem nada a ver com o autoload, e sim com o fato de você estar tentando usar um PDO no namespace `Model\login`

Quando faz `namespace Model\login;` um `new qualquercoisa` vai ser considerado como `Model\login\qualquercoisa`.

Como consequência, seu `autoload` é invocado, e tenta carregar o arquivo nesse caminho (por isso o erro de arquivo não encontrado).

**Solução:**

ou você coloca isso no começo do código:

```
use PDO;
```

Ou então chama no namespace raiz:

```
$con=new \PDO( ...
//       ^-- note a barra
```

assim eliminando a ambiguidade.